# DigitalOcean: I want to download the .env file from server where laravel application installed

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean

I am working on Laravel application on a DigitalOcean server. To speedup my programming I am going to clone my project to my local machine. But I did not find the .env file on the server.

Anyone, please help me getting the .env file from the DigitalOcean server.

Comment: How did you search for the `.env` file? Using the command-line and `ls`? Don't forget that `.env` files are hidden and you need to use `ls -a` to be able to list them.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: And how can change its property hidden to shown?

Comment: You can't really change it in case of `.env` files, all files beginning with a `.` are hidden, if you would remove the `.` from `.env`, your Laravel project would stop working on the server. So instead of renaming the file, I would recommend copying it directly using `scp` as I detailed it below (the important thing is that you know the path to `.env` file on your server, you don't have to actually see it to get it)

Comment: Or another approach would be to run `cat .env` in the repository on the server and copy the contents if that is easier.

Answer (score 2):

The `.env` file is not tracked by git on the server, so when you `git clone` the repository from the server, it will not be included. Depending on the complexity of your project on the server, the `.env` file might include custom variables that are required for the project to function properly. So your best bet is to get a copy of the `.env` file from the server.

To manually copy the `.env` file from the server to your local machine using `scp` or similar tool:

```
$ scp username@server:/repo/.env /some/local/directory
```

Or, if you are using Laravel Forge to deploy to the DigiitalOcean server, you could log in to Forge and copy the contents of the `.env` from the interface.

But don't forget to customize the `.env` afterwards for your local environment (database credentials, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In laravel project , `.env` file exit in the project root file, that does not matter if it is local or live. 
So if you can not find the .evn file in your digital ocean server it is likely that you dont have it in your application .
What you can do is make a copy of `.env.example` and rename it to `.env` file.